# Equalities connected by logical operators

Tags: math-operators, logic, relation-symbols

Most (but not all) of the math-mode stuff in my book consists of terms and formulas of a clean logic:

- The terms are recursively constructed from constants (such as *0*, *1*, *2*, *true*, *f*, *g*, *+*, *∈*, *or*, *not*, … of any arity including 0) and variables (such as *S*, *x*, *y*, …) using applications of terms to other terms (such as *1+x*, *f(0,g(y))*, *x∈S*, …).
- The atomic formulas are of the form *t₁ = t₂*, where *t₁* and *t₂* are terms (such as *3 = x+2*, *x∈S and not false = true*, …).
- The formulas are recursively constructed from atomic formulas using logical negation (*¬*) of formulas (such as *¬(1=2+3)*, *¬(f(x)=g(0,y))*, …), conjunctions (*∧*) and disjunctions (*∨*) (such as *v=2+x ∧ y+2=z*, *v=x ∨ y∈S = true*, …), and variables binders (such as *∃ x: x+1=2*, *∀ x,y: x+y=y+x*, *{x|x+1>y}*, …).

(Btw., all terms have sorts, and there is also a well-sortedness condition imposed on terms and atomic formulas.  We drop this here for simplicity.)

Now, when I typeset my formulas containing equality *=* and binary logical connectives *∧* and *∨*, do I get counterintuitive distances?  E.g., in `v=x \land y=z`, the distances around `\land` (a binary operator in LaTeX) are smaller than around `=` (a relation in LaTeX), aren't they?

If so, what would be the cleanest way to repair this in my setup?  I don't really know and was thinking of something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\formulaConjunction}{\mskip1.2mu plus.6mu minus.6mu\land\mskip1.2mu plus.6mu minus.6mu}
\newcommand{\formulaDisjunction}{\mskip1.2mu plus.6mu minus.6mu\lor\mskip1.2mu plus.6mu minus.6mu}
\newcommand{\memberOf}{\mathbin{\in}}
\begin{document}\noindent
\(v\memberOf S = \mathsf{true} \formulaConjunction y=f(z)\)\\
\(v=x+1 \formulaDisjunction y=z\)
\end{document}
```

This way, the distances around the logical conjunction and disjunction connectives become slightly larger than around the equality symbol of the logic, and the distances around the equality symbol become slightly larger than the distances around infix operators (such as *+*, *∈*), don't they? However, this seems very ad-hoc to me.  Before I change hundreds of formulas in my book this way, are there any potential pitfalls? Is there anything better that works for all of [pdf|xe|lua]latex ? My guess is that the aforementioned logic is somewhat standard, so some someone must have already done this (or at least a similar) exercise.

Comment: Would using parentheses be ok, e.g., `\( (v=x+1) \formulaDisjunction (y=z) \)`?

Comment: @Mico Parens are used to force a formula into a particular tree structure that it wouldn't have with default operator precendences in logics, e.g., ∨ binds weaker than ∧. I'm speaking, on the contrary, about what happens with default operator precendences. You don't want to clutter your formulas with parens when not necessary, after all.

Answer (score 2):

I gather that you would like to change the amount of whitespace TeX inserts around certain symbols of type `mathbin` -- specifically, `\land` and `\lor`, but maybe some others as well. The default amount of whitespace for `mathbin` objects (governed by the parameter `\medmuskip`) is `4mu` in PlainTeX and in all LaTeX document classes I'm familiar with. You may want to increase it to at least `6mu` or  `7mu`. Why not `5mu`, you may ask? Because that's the default value of `\thickmuskip`, the parameter that governs the amount of whitespace around objects with status `mathrel`.

Unfortunately, the number of distinct math-type or math-status categories is quite limited, and none of the existing categories lends itself easily to your typesetting needs. E.g., you don't want to modify the properties of objects with status `mathbin` and `mathrel`, right?

However, I can suggest that you create two new user macros via, say, the instructions

```
\newcommand\Nashland{{\mkern7mu{\land}\mkern7mu}}
\newcommand\Nashlor{{\mkern7mu{\lor}\mkern7mu}}
```

and use `\Nashland` and `\Nashlor` instead of `\land` and `\lor`. Of course, this setup assumes that `\Nashland` and `\Nashlor` will only ever be surrounded by objects with math status `mathord`. That *is* the case in the examples you posted. However, I don't know if this assumption is always valid.

A separate comment: You may be expecting *a lot* -- and quite possibly *too much* -- from your readers if you need them to notice and fully understand the semantic significance of subtle differences in the amounts of whitespace that TeX places around various math objects. In "ordinary" (non-Nash...) notation, there's really no *semantic* significance attached to the amounts of whitespace that surrounds `mathbin` objects -- such as `+` and `-` -- and `mathrel` objects -- such as `=`, `>`, and `<`. I'm pretty sure that one could switch the values of `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` in expressions such as `1+1<2+2` and not cause a major disturbance (though quite possibibly some minor irritation) among readers. But that's not permitted in the use cases that require `\Nashland` and `\Nashlor`, is it? Hence, I think you may be better off using parentheses judiciously and not rely on your readers to truly appreciate the semantic significance of subtle differences in whitespace amounts.

---

Here's an MWE (minimum working example). Note that I've had to set the amount of whitespace involved in `\Nashland` and `\Nashlor` to a whopping `10mu` in order to ensure that readers have no choice but to notice that there must be a non-random, semantic meaning to the amount of whitespace that surrounds the `\land` and `\lor` symbols. Well, you might be able to get by with `9mu` or `8mu` instead of `10mu`; I certainly wouldn't go below `8mu`.

In contrast, using parentheses requires no appreciation at all of subtle differences in whitespace amounts. Parentheses can indeed cause visual clutter. But what's worse: cause some visual clutter, or risk rampant confusion?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' env.
\newcommand{\true}{\mathsf{true}}
%\newcommand{\false}{\mathsf{false}} % not needed for this example

\newcommand\Nashland{{\mkern10mu{\land}\mkern10mu}}
\newcommand\Nashlor{{\mkern10mu{\lor}\mkern10mu}}

\begin{document}

Case 1: \texttt{\string\land} and \texttt{\string\lor}:
\begin{gather*}
v \in S = \true \land y=f(z) \\
v=x+1 \lor y=z
\end{gather*}

\medskip
Case 2: \texttt{\string\Nashland} and \texttt{\string\Nashlor}:
\begin{gather*}
v \in S = \true \Nashland y=f(z) \\
v=x+1 \Nashlor y=z
\end{gather*}

\medskip
Case 3: Parentheses alongside \texttt{\string\land} and \texttt{\string\lor}:
\begin{gather*}
(v \in S = \true) \land (y=f(z)) \\
(v=x+1) \lor (y=z)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sometimes you have a formula spanning several lines, e.g., a conjunction of lines, in which each line starts with `& \land ( …` in an array-like environment, e.g., align*. So the assumption that ∧ and ∨ are always surrounded by Ord is not valid – sometimes there's nothing on one side and an opening symbol on another side, for example. Independent thereof, I wonder what's the point of `\mkern…` instead of `\mskip… plus… minus…`. Don't we want the in-line formulas to stretch, shrink, and break automatically?

Comment: @AlbertNash - You're entirely welcome to replace `\mkern` with `\mskip`. If the main length is 10mu, I wouldn't see the point of adding puny stretch and shrink components, as in  `plus .6mu minus.6mu`. `plus 3mu minus 3mu` might be more useful in practice.

Comment: Thanks! It's more about the relative values of stretch and shrink rather than the absolute values. So far, I've beein using 50%: \mskipmu plus(/2)mu minus(/2)mu, whether it's `\mskip1.2mu plus.6mu minus.6mu` or `\mskip12mu plus6mu minus6mu`. You seem to favour 30% in your comment above: `\mskip10mu plus 3mu minus 3mu`. Any specific reason behind it?

Comment: As for my 50%: the computation of a half in my book comes from macros that automatically set an elastic positive or negative space: `\newcommand{\flexAddMSpace}[1]{\mskip#1 plus.5\muexpr#1\relax minus.5\muexpr#1\relax\relax}
\newcommand{\flexReduceMSpace}[1]{\mskip-#1 plus.5\muexpr#1\relax minus.5\muexpr#1\relax\relax}` I have no particular reason to take exactly one half. 
Concerning puny values: a single tiny stretch or shrink does nothing in my experience, but if they accumulate from various sources in a single line, it sometimes makes a difference. E.g., an overfull sometimes disappears.

Comment: @AlbertNash - In order to be able to distinguish readily between `\thickmuskip` (5mu plus minus some stretching and shrinking) and whatever amount of whitespace should surround `\land` and `\lor`, I don't think that this "whatever amount" should be less than 8mu. *Maybe* 7mu, if `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` also get shrunk. Hence, a mild preference for `10mu plus 3mu minus 3mu`.

Comment: The defaults are IMHO `\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu` and `\thickmuskip = 5mu plus 5mu`, but we can surely redefine them, perhaps, locally for the formulas in my logic, if we think this would do any good.

Comment: @AlbertNash - You are absolutely free to change the values of the values of `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`  however which way you see fit. As I noted in my answer, TeX and LaTeX do not imbue these parameters with any semantic meaning *per se*.  If you expect your readers to attach semantic meanings to these parameters, you better tell them about this plan of yours in painstaking detail. Just don't be too disappointed if your readers don't show a huge amount of enthusiasm over this innovation...

Comment: It's just for the reader not to *unintentionally* misread a=b∧c=d as a=(b∧c)=d. It's impossible to safely underestimate a student…

Comment: @AlbertNash - Well, you know I'm not averse to using parentheses...

Answer (score 1):

You may want, in select places, change the nature of `=` and `\in` to be binary operations rather than relations.

You possibly need other symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\true}{\mathsf{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\mathsf{false}}

\newcommand{\logic}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \expanded{\mathchardef\in = \the\numexpr\in-"1000}%
  \mathcode`= = \numexpr\mathcode`=-"1000\relax
  #1
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

\[
\logic{v \in S = \true \land y=f(z)}
\]

\[
\logic{v=x+1 \lor y=z}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First, if we do this, wouldn't the space around *=* be the same as around *+*? Ideally, we should have the space around infix operators (such as *+*, *\**, or *∈*) slightly smaller than the space around *=*, and the space around ∨ and ∧ slightly larger than the space around *=*. Second, would this work in {xelua}latex? I thought we would need something like `\Umathchardef` instead of `\mathchardef`.